# change mp4 `ftyp` from `isom` to `mp42`

Tags: encoding, mp4, video-conversion, video-editing

Will I be able to change the `ftyp` of an mp4 file?

I have two mp4 files and placed it unto media info to see what is the difference. The other mp4 plays on my SanDisk Sansa Fuze device while the other does not. The one that is playing has an `ftyp` of `mp42`. The one I encoded using `megui` uses `isom` as its codec id.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ffmpeg could do the job.

```
ffmpeg -i isom.mp4 -brand mp42 mp42.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like [WinFF](http://www.biggmatt.com/winff/) to convert the files for you, it has quite a few low-level functions you may be looking for.